# Connection string not working with default user authentication

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I am new to Visual studio and I am trying to connect to database. I am using default windows authentication. On application login page when I enter login user name and password, I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot open database "myDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'VSERVER90\IWPD_1(tappaas)'.
```

When I right click on connection the server name is "`VSERVER90`" and authentication is "`windows authentication`" selected. 
These are working in management studio.

I don't know where the IWPD_1 is coming from and why I am not able to login.

Comment: Did you check your web.config file?

Comment: specify your connection string in question

Comment: It is possible that VS is running under an other account than the instance of your asp.net application. Try to find your connection-string, and preferably use sql-authentication.\

Comment: sorted the problem by adding the user 'VSERVER90\IWPD_1(tappaas)' in security/login and assigned the permission. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is setup for "Windows Authentification". This means, that you don't need user name and password for your database, and you simply login with your current windows user name.

Now, your project seems to have a "login " page; however, whatever you insert here, it is **not** taken, because your windows user is taken. The name of your user `VSERVER90\IWPD_1(tappaas)`